# Using detail disclosure buttons on section headers

Tags: icons, mobile-application, help

My colleague is suggesting to add a detail disclosure icon to a section header in a mobile app. It seems rather cluttered to me given the density of info we already have on the screen.

Are there any alternatives to this that could help address this request?

For instance, a one-time onboarding modal to highlight the section, and then info in a help section for subsequent viewing?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are there multiple sections in that particular view that you are referring to? What happens when clicking the header?

Answer (score 1):

For me is hard to say without seeing a real case but you can use one of these components:

- **Onboarding Modal:** As you suggested, a one-time onboarding modal can introduce users to the key features and sections of the app. This would help them understand the purpose of the section header without adding clutter to the interface.
- **Tooltip:** Use a small, unobtrusive tooltip icon (e.g., a question mark) near the section header that, when tapped, displays a brief description of the section. This approach can convey information without taking up too much screen real estate.
- **Progressive Disclosure:** Gradually reveal information only when users need it. For example, tapping on the section header could expand it to display additional information or options. This keeps the interface clean and focuses on the most crucial information by default.
- **Animated Walkthrough:** Create a short, animated walkthrough that users can access at any time. This can help visually demonstrate how to navigate the app and interact with its features.
- **Contextual Hints:** Provide hints or visual cues contextually, only when necessary. For instance, if the user seems to be struggling to find certain functionality or hasn't interacted with the section header, a subtle hint could appear, guiding them towards it

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use iOS standard solution: arrow disclosure icon in table rows. It leads to a next screen with a Back button. 
[image]

Another options is (i) icon, which is used when it's mostly helpful info you are putting onto next screen, and not actions.

[image]

As this solution is recommended by guideline https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/tables/, you can easily argue with your colleague.

Comment: Daria, thank you so much for the link. In this case, we don't have a table view to anchor the disclosure button, but it's definitely helpful to see the sample above. Thank you.